# how to fix python iteration for some 2D time dependent diffusion function using implicit schem

Tags: python, matlab

HI I'm new at this site and I'm looking for an answer for my python code

my code is simply solve groundwater head diffusion (using 2d implicit differentiation). in other words, I'm solving the function as time dependent
with Laplace Equation : d^2h/dx^2+d^2h/dy^2 = ds/dt
where dh is the change of head over flow path (dx = dy) in space
ds is some constant value (storage coefficient) and dt is the time increment

so I do solved the example under the condition of to boundary conditions upstream 5 m and down stream of 3 m and my grid is 7x7 cells

I solved the problem using C# and matlab and both answers were close after conversions ( which reach the equilibrium for some exact analytical solution) but when I used Python my solution didn't reach the equilibrium

here is my code with python

```
 import numpy as np

h = np.zeros((7,7,10))
h0 = 5.
K = 2.
DT = 1.
DX = 100.
S = 0.0005
B = 8.
D = (K*B)/S
r = (D*DT)/(DX*DX)

dummy = h.shape
nrow = dummy[0]
ncol = dummy[1]
ntm = dummy[2]
print 'Groundwater Head matrix is a ', nrow, ' by ', ncol, ' matrix.','with',ntm,'increments'
for i in range(nrow):
    for j in  range(ncol):
        for k in range(1):
         h[i,j,k] = h0
         continue

        h[0:,0,1:] = 5.
        h[0:,6,1:] = 3.

        ni = 1
conv_crit = 1e-9
converged = False
while (not converged):
  max_err = 0
  for i in range(1, nrow - 1):
      for j in range(1,ncol - 1):
          for k in range(1,ntm-1):

            h_old = h[i,j,k+1]
            h[i,j,k+1] = (r*h[i-1,j,k+1]+r*h[i+1,j,K+1]+r*h[i,j-1,K+1]+
                          r*h[i,j+1,k+1]+h[i,j,k])/(1+4*r)

            h[0,0:6,k+1] = h[2,0:6,k+1]
            h[6,0:6,k+1] = h[4,0:6,k+1]

            diff = h[i,j,k+1] - h_old
            if (diff > max_err):
             max_err = diff
  if (max_err <= conv_crit):
      converged = True
  ni = ni + 1
  print 'Number of iterations = ', ni - 1
  print h[0:,0:,9]
  print ' Error =', max_err
```

this is my result with python

```
Number of iterations =  132
[[ 5.          4.40796148  3.88890558  3.5072111   3.24606331  3.0865587  3.     ]
 [ 5.          4.40796148  3.88890558  3.5072111   3.24606331  3.0865587  3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.40796148  3.88890558  3.5072111   3.24606331  3.0865587  3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.40796148  3.88890558  3.5072111   3.24606331  3.0865587  3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.40796148  3.88890558  3.5072111   3.24606331  3.0865587  3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.40796148  3.88890558  3.5072111   3.24606331  3.0865587  3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.40796148  3.88890558  3.5072111   3.24606331  3.0865587  3.        ]]
 Error = 9.17176556925e-10
```

and here with matlab

```
5.0000    4.6599    4.3229    3.9892    3.6583    3.3291    3.0000
    5.0000    4.6592    4.3217    3.9879    3.6573    3.3285    3.0000
    5.0000    4.6599    4.3229    3.9892    3.6583    3.3291    3.0000
    5.0000    4.6606    4.3240    3.9904    3.6593    3.3296    3.0000
    5.0000    4.6613    4.3250    3.9915    3.6602    3.3301    3.0000
    5.0000    4.6619    4.3259    3.9925    3.6610    3.3305    3.0000
    5.0000    4.6613    4.3250    3.9915    3.6602    3.3301    3.0000
```

matlab use only 41 iteration

Notice that I used the Gauss Seidel Iteration

Comment: Which is correct, your python implementation, or your matlab one? (or neither?)

Comment: Matlab is ok, but python which I'm having problem with is not . To explain more take one row from matlab result  and one row from python the same row  ( from 5 to 3 ) you can see that the matlab result are more linear while python is curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured it out what is wrong with my python code

I should let

```
for k in range(ntm-1):
```

instead of

```
 for k in range(1, ntm-1):
```

Since python first element in matrix is start with zero , and that where my initial condition head value is occur. That is, at transient the groundwater head will start diffuse to reach equilibrium and the head will take the shape of straight (linear) line
(I keep mixed with python indexing with matlab which start with one)
and here is my final result

```
   5.          4.67229917  4.34411362  4.01349084  3.67944236  3.34142973  3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.67207003  4.34374374  4.01309249  3.6791206   3.3412565   3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.67229917  4.34411362  4.01349084  3.67944236  3.34142973  3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.67251271  4.34445832  4.01386208  3.67974223  3.34159116  3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.67271172  4.34477956  4.01420805  3.68002168  3.34174161  3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.67289718  4.34507894  4.01453048  3.68028211  3.34188181  3.        ]
 [ 5.          4.67271172  4.34477956  4.01420805  3.68002168  3.34174161  3.        ]]
 Error = 0.00088610885882
```

even the number of Iteration has improved which toke only 49 iterations

THANKS EVERYONE

***NOTICE that I changed my tolerance value from 1e-9 to 1e-3 in the previous code